# How to make WinHttpRequest as double? (runtime error 13)

Tags: vba, runtime, mismatch

I kindly ask you for help with this, as I am becoming frustrated AF.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Calc()
Dim EBITDA As Double
Dim EnterValue As Double
Dim EqValue As Double
Dim OperProfit As Double
Dim Depreciation As Double
Dim NetDebt As Double
Dim EqValueEUR As Double
Dim ExRate As Double
Dim ExchangeRate As Double


Dim URL As String: URL = "https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURCZK%3DX&f=b"
Dim yahooCE As New WinHttpRequest
yahooCE.Open "GET", URL, False
yahooCE.Send
ExchangeRate = yahooCE.ResponseText

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("C23").Value = ExchangeRate
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("B22").Value = "Convert to EUR"
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("C22").Value = "Yes"
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("B23").Value = "Exchange rate"
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("B22").Value = "Convert to EUR"
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("C22").Value = "No"
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("B24").Value = "Equity value in EUR"
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Healthcare" Then Mult = 6
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Industrials" Then Mult = 3
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Consumer Staples" Then Mult = 3.5
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Consumer Discretionary" Then Mult = 1.5
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Utilities" Then Mult = 2
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Energy" Then Mult = 2.5
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Materials" Then Mult = 4.5
    If ComboBox1.Value = "IT" Then Mult = 7


OperProfit = OpProfit
Depreciation = Deprec


EBITDA = OperProfit + Depreciation
EnterValue = EBITDA * Mult
NetDebt = Loan.Value - Cash.Value
EqValue = EnterValue - NetDebt
**EqValueEUR = EqValue / ExchangeRate** 

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("C24").Value = EqValueEUR


Range("C15").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = EBITDA
Range("C16").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = Mult
Range("C17").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = EnterValue
Range("C18").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = NetDebt
Range("C19").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = EqValue
```

It pops up Runtime error type 13, because the downloaded value to ExchangeRate is treated as String, however in the bold equation we are mixing Double (EqValue) and String (ExchangeRate) - I understand the cause of the problem. However, I am not able to find a way how to fix it.

Is there a way to force Excel to treat the downloaded value as Double or somehow to bypass it?

Thank you!

Comment: ExchangeRate is declared As Double, so that should not be the problem here.

Comment: i cringed when i saw the last few lines of your code  ... do not use `activate ... active` to assign a value to a cell, use the same format as in the `if ... then ...` statement above

Comment: What are the values of `EqValue`  and `ExchangeRate` when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

since the answer to http is text and Exchangerate is double you need to convert from text to double

```
ExchangeRate = CDbl(yahooCE.ResponseText)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still pops up the same mismatch error.

New code:
    `Dim URL As String: URL =
    "https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?
    s=EURCZK%3DX&f=b"
    Dim yahooCE As New WinHttpRequest
    yahooCE.Open "GET", URL, False
    yahooCE.Send
    ExchangeRate = CDbl(yahooCE.ResponseText)
    ExRate = ExchangeRate`

What is going on here?

Comment: `ExchangeRate` is declared As Double, so if there no error on `ExchangeRate = yahooCE.ResponseText` then CDbl shouldn't change anything here

Comment: The problem is, in my opinion, that ExchangeRate is String since it is downloaded from Yahoo, but ExRate is defined as Double, so when the code runs `ExRate = ExchangeRate` it pops up mismatch error. However, when I try to force ExchangeRate as Double by CDbl, it pops up error on `ExchangeRate = CDbl(yahooCE.ResponseText)`.

Comment: @adaz, the following code works on my computer `Private Sub Calc()
Dim EBITDA As Double
Dim EnterValue As Double
Dim EqValue As Double
Dim OperProfit As Double
Dim Depreciation As Double
Dim NetDebt As Double
Dim EqValueEUR As Double
Dim ExRate As Double
Dim ExchangeRate As Double


Dim URL As String
URL = "https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURCZK%3DX&f=b"
Dim yahooCE As New WinHttpRequest
yahooCE.Open "GET", URL, False
yahooCE.Send
ExchangeRate = yahooCE.ResponseText
End Sub`